# Initial number part or integer portion of a string in xsl

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xpath, numbers

By using xsl template, can any one tell me the way to get first number portion of a string field

For example:

```
'12'        -> should result in -> 12
'5 ASDF'    -> should result in -> 5
'34SDF56'   -> should result in -> 34
```

Comment: What version of XSL are you using? What XSL processor?

Comment: I am using version 1.0 and cooktop...

Comment: see my general solution.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest solution :)

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a one-liner XPath solution**:  :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vS" select="concat(.,'Z')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(translate($vS,translate($vS,'0123456789',''),'Z'),'Z')"/>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <x>12</x>
 <x>5 ASDF</x>
 <x>34SDF56</x>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct results are produced**:

```
12
5
34
```

Comment: @Alejandro and @LarsH: I think you'd be interested to see this solution :)

Comment: why do you append the Z character to the string?  Why can't use just use the value of the text node?

Comment: @Peter-Jacoby: This expression works OK for strings that start with digits followed by nondigit(s). If the string contains only digits, the empty string will be returned as result. This is way I append a 'Z' to the string before I process it.

Comment: thanks for the tag. Good point, the concat-Z helps make the code tighter: fewer conditionals... again, at the cost of readability. I also wonder about the potential cost of creating more, immutable strings. Nice trick, translating all non-numerics to 'Z' via a translated second argument to translate(). :-)

Comment: +1 Good answer. It could be also `substring-before($vS,substring(translate($vS,'0123456789',''),1,1))` preserving the meaning *"the string before first not digit"* and ussing three functions calls.

Answer (score 1):

you could give this a go? should work supposing that you know the maximum length of numbers!

so here you could find a number upto 6 digits long! hope it helps

```
      <xsl:variable name="YourString" select="YourStringPath"/>
      <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,6) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,6)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,5) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,5)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,4) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,4)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,3) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,2) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,2)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($YourString,1,1) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring($YourString,1,1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>default number here?</xsl:otherwise>         
      </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this solution works and I needed upto 5 numbers, so I can easily amend your code to get up to 5 numbers by eliminating the first when statement.

Comment: Now I need the remaining string without leading spaces. For example I want '5 ASDF' to return 'ASDF', and '12ASDF 34' to return 'ASDF 34'.

Answer (score 0):

The following template will emit all numeric digits of a string up to the first non-numeric (without having to know how many digits may be in the number):

```
   <xsl:template match="@num">
      <xsl:variable name="nonNumbers" select="translate(., '0123456789', '')"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$nonNumbers">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,
                                        substring($nonNumbers, 1, 1))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>            
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
```

(Thanks to @Alejandro for the key idea, using substring() to get the first non-number, and then passing it to substring-before().) Here it is in the context of an identity transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="@num">
      <xsl:variable name="nonNumbers" select="translate(., '0123456789', '')"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$nonNumbers">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., substring($nonNumbers, 1, 1))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>            
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<values>
   <value num="12"/>
   <value num="5 ASDF"/>
   <value num="34SDF56"/>
</values>
```

it produces the requested output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values>
   <value num="12"/>
   <value num="5"/>
   <value num="34"/>
</values>
```

Another way to do the `@num` template is the following, arguably more elegant but harder to read IMO:

```
 <xsl:template match="@num[translate(., '0123456789', '') = '']">
    <!-- alternatively, match="@num[number(.) > 0]" -->
    <xsl:copy />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="@num">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., substring(
                                 translate(., '0123456789', ''), 1, 1))" />
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
```

Notes:

- The first of the two @num templates above takes **priority** over the second, because the first is more specific, having a predicate. So the first template is used to process @num's that it matches, and the second template processes all other @num's.
- The first template matches @num's whose value is all digits, and merely copies the attribute. If we didn't make this exception, the second template would output empty string values for such @num's.