# Select substrings dependent on context

Tags: xslt

I have this piece of XML and want to get the number immediately after `Chapter`

```
<para>Insolvency Rules, r 12.12, which gives the court a broad discretion, unfettered by the English equivalent of the heads of Order 11, r 1(1) (which are now to be found, in England, in CPR, Chapter 6, disapplied in the insolvency context by Insolvency Rules, r 12.12(1)). </para>
```

When I used this XSLT transform

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(current(),'Chapter'), translate(substring-after(current(),'Chapter'),'0123456789',''), '')"/>
```

I get this output

```
612121
```

Butut I want just `6`.

Please let me know how I should do it.

I don't want to use a statement like

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(current(),'Chapter'), ,',')"/>
```

as the chapter number will be different in each instance, between 1 and 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="vS" select="concat(substring-after(current(),'Chapter '),'Z')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select=
           "substring-before(translate($vS,translate($vS,'0123456789',''),'Z'),'Z')"/>
```

This is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188249/2115381 Thanks to 
@Dimitre Novatchev

Update: If the quantity of space after the "Chapter" is not known you can use something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="vS" select="concat(substring-after(current(),'Chapter'),'Z')"/>

<xsl:value-of select=
        " translate(
        substring-before(translate($vS,translate($vS,' 0123456789',''),'Z'),'Z')
     , ' ','')"/>
```